# How to run gulp tasks sequentially?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a few tasks in gulp and all of them except one could be run in parallel. Let's consider an example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    // clean up output folder
});
gulp.task('copy1', function() {
    // writes stream in the output folder
});
gulp.task('copy2', function() {
    // writes stream in the output folder
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'copy1', 'copy2']);
```

In this example I need to run `copy1` and `copy2` in parallel but only after `clean`. How can I do this trick?

Comment: [gulp-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence)

Comment: BTW I've tried `gulp-sequence`, it works without issues.

Answer (score 5):

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence('clean', ['copy1', 'copy2'], callback);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**Be careful** - there is a bug in gulp 3.x where even when using runSequence, the stream will return premature when file i/o is involved. [Check out this post if you have issues:](https://medium.com/@willbittner/gulp-v3-x-hack-to-fix-error-gulp-resolve-dependencies-file-not-found-and-tasks-being-executed-d6b8f9df7df3)